# Does adding a point to a triangle make it a quadrilateral? and if so can a triangle be any polygon?

Tags: triangles, polygons, quadrilateral

Does adding a point to a triangle make it a quadrilateral? and if so can a triangle be any polygon?

does the next triangle a quadrilateral?

[image: Image of 4 points on a triangle. Is this a quadrilateral?]

Or, does a point have to change a side angle?

Thank you for any help, I am new here and I opened this question because of an argument with my math teacher and classmates.

Comment: No answers yet?

Comment: Most people require polygons to be non-degenerate by explicitly prohibiting this. But there's no reason why you have to do that, nothing will break, you just have a weird quadrilateral. By adding 180 degree angles in this way, the resulting polygon still has the correct total angle, for example.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger is there any way to get real proof that the polygon in the image is actually a quadrilateral?

Comment: What is your definition of a quadrilateral?

Comment: @IvanNeretin you are the Ph.D. you tell me, I tried to search for it on the internet, and got no real answer for it, the question I asked is challenging the definition of a quadrilateral.
And what do you mean by "your definition"? there is not supposed to be an "official" definition?

Comment: Exactly. It is up to you to decide.

Comment: Start with any quadrilateral $\square ABCD$ with sides $AB, BC, CD, DA$. Choose any corner of the quadrilateral. Without loss of generality, let the chosen corner by $A$. There are two triangles $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle BCD$, the former containing the chosen corner $A$ and the latter not containing the chosen corner $A$.

If you keep pushing the corner $A$ (either inward towards the centroid or outward) so that it is ultimately collinear with points $B$ and $D$, then the triangle $\triangle ABD$ degenerates to the line $BD$ and $\square ABCD \cong \triangle BCD$.

Comment: @Apophis, the "you are the PhD, you tell me" attitude is not going to get you very far here...

Comment: If you generalize this to a polygon, the requirement is that if any three adjacent points on the polygon are collinear, then the middle point is redundant. You can remove it and obtain an $(n-1)$-gon from an $n$-gon. You can repeat this process recursively until you are left with a set of non-redundant points that determine whether you get a triangle, quadrilateral, pentagon or $m$-vertex polygon.

Comment: Thank you @vvg very helpful, you think there is a way to display it visually?

Comment: And @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  sorry if I sounded offensive, did not mean to, tried to be friendly, my English is not that good to determine.

Comment: The way you have drawn the triangle (in Desmos, I suppose), you can just draw another chart with the point $B$ NOT collinear with $A$ and $C$. You can move $B$ in any direction and you will have a quadrilateral. The image you have in the question will be the end state after you push the point back to be collinear. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: In general, mathematics does not have "official" definitions, because there is no central authority that decides these things.